# How can I display output of array on a form?

Tags: c#, arrays, output

i am having trouble displaying this array output to a form.
what is the issue I am sure it is an easy fix and being new to c# programming i seem to find my error

```
class Program
    {
        public static void Menu ()
        {
            string[] names = { "Bob Johnson", "Amy Larsen", "Reed McMichels", "Mary Jones", "Sheila Stone" };
            for (int i = 0; i < names.Length; i++)
            {
                Console.WriteLine(names[i]);
```

Comment: You say "form" but you are trying to write to the `Console`. Where do you want the output to be displayed?

Comment: `Console.WriteLine`, as you can guess by the name, is used for _consoles_. What does your form look like? Is this WinForms?

Comment: i am using Visual Studio 2109 winforms

Comment: You haven't posted any code that relates to WinForms.

Comment: For WinForms you can use anything from a ListBox to a DataGridView

Comment: You have to select project template as Windows Forms application when you create the project in VS2019 IDE. Here, you have created a console application, which will work in command prompt.

Answer (score 0):

As i can see, there is no Winforms code for the question but here is your answer!

`string[] names = { "Bob Johnson", "Amy Larsen", "Reed McMichels","Mary Jones", "Sheila Stone"}; foreach (var name in names){ Console.WriteLine(name); }`